# Why is reputation loss reverted after a downvoted answer/question is deleted

Tags: discussion, reputation, deleted-answers

Why is reputation loss reverted after a downvoted answer/question is deleted?

Why after posting a wrong answer which gets downvotes and then deleting it does negative reputation disappear?

Comment: You want to get negative reputation points for deleted content?

Comment: Well i think is fair to be punished for wrong answer and then covering it up

Comment: @Ziker ``punished''...

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It encourages self-policing. Otherwise multiple other users will have to agree that the post should be closed and/or deleted. (The details vary depending on whether the post is a question or an answer.) If the OP deletes by themselves, it is that much work saved for other people. Hopefully, they also gain some realization as they delete their post that it was not a good post in the first place.

If you are concerned about people posting terrible stuff, deleting it, regaining their rep and reposting again, know that the ban algorithms also look at posts that were deleted. So someone who makes a habit of it will soon be banned from posting altogether.

Comment: Although i believe in "crime-punishment" method this answer is acceptable for me thx:)

Comment: I can attest, having posted a bad question and shortly after answering my own q with my well intentioned answer, watching the downvotes come pouring in was heartbreaking and felt awful, instantly erasing ANY of the meager reputation I had managed to scrape together. Having a Mod delete the Q and having those downvotes undone was quite a sigh of relief, but it didn't undo the dread and panic of "oh crap what have I done why am I hated so much". Those feels are still very real. "Punishment" enough, I would say.