# What to do when my comment has been reposted as an answer by another user?

Tags: discussion, questions, answers, comments, attribution

As a fairly new active user on SO, there is this question that was so simple I answered it in the comment. I didn't want to post my thoughts as an answer as, again, the question was so simple I wasn't sure of what the OP was asking.

It turned out that several SO users took advantage of it to post my comment as an answer. No answer have been accepted yet by the OP but I sense that what I posted is what the OP wanted.

I had a look at similar question on SO meta such as [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/274776/proper-to-downvote-a-user-who-posts-the-same-answer-later-on/274818#274818) and [this other one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258558/how-to-deal-with-a-stolen-answer) but my situation is slightly different as I posted my answer in the comments.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/179419

Comment: I have slightly modified your title. I believe that will reduce the number of "instinctive downvotes" this question may get. Feel free to rollback the edit if that actually was the exact semantics you were going for.

Comment: Here's a nice sample:http://stackoverflow.com/a/23984128/1413395 You can't do that much about it :-P ...

Comment: Related: [Question with no answers but issue solved in the comments](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251597)

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi No need for me to rollback, this is better. One last question though, shouldn't the `4` upvotes make me gain me some reputation points?

Comment: @D4V1D, not on per-site metas, no. Only [meta.se] has separate reputation (since it technically doesn't have a "main" site).

Comment: "What to do?" Learn to post answers instead of posting comments, if the information answers the question. If you choose to provide it in a comment, and someone else uses that info (or happens to know it as well) and posts it, it's their gain and your loss.

Comment: I researched a question a while ago, just to find someone else posted my exact same findings [as a mere comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28756025/assembly-language-changing-color-of-characters)… So I made my answer a wiki-community.

Comment: The placeholder for the comment box says not to post answers in comments.

Comment: tempted to steal the comment of @KenWhite and add as my answer ..

Comment: Sorry, but what makes you think that it was *your* comment that inspired the answer?

Comment: Because there were only one interaction with the question and it was my comment. And the answer copied the exact characters of my comment all the way until the quotes used. To be edited afterwards.

Comment: Not related but worth reading: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288530/should-every-question-have-an-answer

Comment: In my experience you can't do anything, I've been the victim of this a few times. One of those times I flagged the answer for moderator attention that it stole my comment, flag was declined.

Comment: As per the comments/answers, I'm not sure `victim` is the right word here. Answering question in comments is not adviced so if we do, there's nothing to do if an user uses this comment to make an answer.

Comment: I admonish others for doing this (answering in comments). But I'm a hypocrite and I do it too sometimes. Not sure why, but I have a theory that it's because I'm too lazy to flesh out a full answer, but at the same time I take satisfaction in demonstrating that I do in fact know the answer to a question. Of course, I don't care if someone "steals" my comment and makes an answer out of it. After all, the timestamp is there to prove that I knew it fastest, so my ego is sated.

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285406/is-there-such-thing-as-an-answer-that-is-too-simple

Comment: But what if there is not enough information to be confident that the answer would be right? It seemed common sense to me to post a comment saying "Could you try this and tell us the result?", a simple query for further information. Especially, when it seems like something really obvious to do. Should we just write as many answers as we can, as fast as we can, without asking further questions in case someone may steal them and post as an answer?

Answer (score 95, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. a user sees your comment, realizes it solves the OP's issue as written and writes an answer that copies the comment.
2. A user sees your comment, and it inspires their own answer.
3. A user does not see your comment, but chooses to post an answer around the same time you posted that comment +/- a minute to start drafting it. By coincidence, the answer and comment are identical (we see this a lot with really easy questions, because there's only one way to do it given the code that's written).

There's nothing wrong any of these possibilities.  To be 'nice', they should reference where they came up with the answer from (if it's another answer), but it's certainly not a requirement. As far as referencing a comment in their answer; that's also nice, but unless it's foolproof that they copied the comment as their answer, there's no way to tell if they should.

If anything, answers are better than comments because comments are ephemeral and can be deleted at any time, for any reason.

So, to answer your question:

> What to do when my comment has been stolen as another answer by another user?

Answer the question instead of commenting.

Of course, if it's wrong, you'll have downvotes; but if the person who steals your comment and posts it as an answer is wrong, they'll have downvotes.

Since you have the ability to edit, you can always edit in a link to your comment and that you are the source of the answer.  If they delete that, then that says something about their intent, doesn't it?

Comment: I would think attribution is a requirement if they are going to just copy-paste, given the license we give content posted here.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET IANAL. I'll leave it to the lawyers to decide whether that's the case for comments. I have a hard enough time writing code without bugs, let alone trying to interpret legal documents.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my question fastly. I'll try to answer more but I'm avoiding downvotes at all costs. Thanks for the edit suggestion :)

Comment: @D4V1D It can always backfire on you; as the other answer points out, checking the timestamps is key. If they posted the answer within a minute of you posting the comment, it's quite likely you simply thought of the same answer at the same time.

Comment: I have checked timestamps on that one. Answers have been posted fairly enough time after my comment and were exactly mine. They have been edited since so I'm not gonna flag them but thank you for your advice.

Comment: @D4V1D: just follow your conscience, don't worry about upvotes or downvotes too much. Downvotes can be avoided by deleting the content you posted that generated them. In any case, I'm not aware of any specific rule against copying a comment and posting as an answer. As George says, that's a risk you take when you post an answer as a comment instead. Want credit for the answer? Post the answer. (Frankly, few things annoy me more than wasting my time looking at a "unanswered" question that has an answer, except that the answer is really just buried in the comments).

Comment: @PeterDuniho Thanks for commenting. Do you mean that if I delete a 5-downvotes answer, I'll gain my réputation back?

Comment: @D4V1D: [that's my understanding](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252147/why-is-reputation-loss-reverted-after-downvoted-answer-question-is-deleted)

Comment: "Answer the question instead of commenting" - this! If you have an answer, answer it! In the answer box! As an answer! Why the heck is my ! key malfunctioning? Comments have always been considered second-class citizens, the is a Q&A site, not a Q&A&C one :-)

Comment: "*There's nothing wrong any of these*" OMG no, #1 is most definitely wrong. It's taking credit for someone else's contribution, regardless of the technicality of what's a comment and what's a question. The right thing to do is to post a community wiki answer, or give full attribution.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisCorbett I disagree. (*Though I, personally, do give attribution in that case, and try to add to it*) - answers in comments are generally uncertain guesses, or theories. When someone makes it into an answer, they are taking your theory and putting it to the test. If you really want full credit, post it where you will receive full credit.. I don't really see it as "taking credit" for the answer - anyone can see the comment was posted before right there on the same page.

Comment: In short: you have credit for your comment. Someone else has the credit for the posted answer. If you want credit for the answer, post it as an answer.

Comment: Whether the person who posted an answer-comment "wants credit" or not is irrelevant. If you're taking someone else's content and claiming it as your own, it's plagiarism — regardless of where you found that content, be it in a comment, an answer, some other website, a book, a post-it note. Plagiarism is bad, so let's not do it. But sure, if you add some extra content (example, testing, etc.), that you can legitimately claim as your own.

Comment: It's really weird that the answerer writes "it's certainly not a requirement." in regard to attribution and then in the comments writes that they're uncertain if it is true or not. Has the word "certainly" no meaning?

Answer (score 33):

If you have the answer, *do not post it as a comment*. Why is this such a fashion nowadays?

All of your queries become moot once you stop doing this.

Comment: It's pretty much my default behavior when "search for duplicate" fails on the first try and I know the question is a duplicate.  This is, unfortunately, the most common scenario for the tags I frequent.

Comment: @AndrewC: No offence but I think that's terrible behaviour! Not only are you encourage posting what must then be obvious duplicates (obvious otherwise without having even found the originals you wouldn't have known), but in doing so breaking the Q&A model. Nothing's right about this!

Comment: Are you suggesting answering the obvious questions is better, or simply downvote and moving on?

Comment: @AndrewC: Vote to close as duplicate and move on!

Comment: For the tag I frequent (git), searching for duplicates is usually a time consuming and frustrating experience - posting a comment isn't.  You could make an argument that if search isn't finding them as a duplicate then perhaps they aren't duplicates, but this seems to be an issue with the search facility.

Comment: @AndrewC: If you don't have time to find a dupe then don't, but that's no excuse to instead write answers as comments let alone on dupes. IMO. BTW yes I agree about search, and usually use Google for the task.

Comment: I'll rethink my strategy.  Now if we could just everyone else to stop upvoting dupes and posting answers on them.

Comment: @AndrewC: Yeah :(

Answer (score 20):

First off, never assume malicious intent until you have cause to. Check the timestamps of the answers. Were they close to when you posted your comment? Its quite possible that they posted the same concept without even *seeing* what you wrote.

Secondly, this is actually *encouraged* practice since people shouldn't be answering in comments. It is preferred, however, to give the original commenter a chance to post by asking him to post the comment as an answer in a comment-reply. If they did that, and provided attribution in the answer, then they have done nothing wrong. It is considered courteous to make the answer community-wiki in that case.

As long as they attribute you, they are technically OK (your content is licensed by CC-SA). If they blatantly ripped off your post however, and didn't do any of the above, first leave a comment asking them to provide attribution to you, and possibly make their answer community-wiki. If they refuse, flag the post for plagarism. A moderator will take care of it.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question that fast. I never assume malicious intent but on that one, answer have been posted fairly after my comment so no doubt here. I understand that answering is more encouraged than commenting, despites the possibility of downvotes. And the answers were exactly mine, all the way until the quotes used. They have been edited afterwards though. That is why I am not gonna flag them for plagarism.

Comment: WHY?  The aim here is to have a question and a correct answer.  The end result is good, whether the comment was copied or not.  Just upvote the answer (because presumably you believe it's useful) and move on.

Comment: @DavidWallace For the same reason that just copying another *answer* is plagiarism. Granted, an answer is far superior to a comment, but that shouldn't give users carte-blanche to not even attribute their source.

Answer (score 13):

The most important thing to understand here is that having a correct answer is by far the most important thing.

A comment is not an answer.

Site reputation and attribution of answers to their authors are just tools being used to encourage generation of correct and high quality answers.

Thus, the person who posted the answer was completing the desired process.

Answer (score 13):

#### Reposting as an answer is great — but no excuse for plagiarism

I've [reposted other people's comments as answers many times](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A119775%20wiki%3A1). I do this because that's where answer-like content should go — in answers, not comments.

But I always make sure to make it a community wiki answer. That way there's no taking credit for someone else's contribution. (Votes and acceptances on community wiki answers don't count toward anyone's reputation.)

[image]

(To illustrate the point in a meta way, I made this answer you're reading right now a community wiki.)

#### Now to answer your question more specifically

What can you do about your situation after the fact? Not much, I'm afraid. Except leave a comment appealling to the answerer's conscience to make it community wiki, or at least give you full attribution. Other than that, learn your lesson and move on.

Comment: Your replies actually seem to be a lot more than just repeating the comments. You add examples, you reformat, merge several together, etc. I think you'd be justified in not using community wiki on the ones I looked at!

Comment: Yeah, for some of them, I ended up redecorating a little bit, but for a lot of them I really just slapped the comment into an answer and left it at that. I just think plagiarism stinks and I want to stay as far away from it as possible.

Comment: i completely agree to this point, because i myself often use this method. not because i would not be able to answer the question myself, i mainly do this, if i think the question is worth while reading for others and the answer should deserve a better block than in the comments and maybe deserves a bit more explanation - if not for the original questioner, than at least for follow readers - but DEFINATLY should such answers include reference. Checking `community wiki` seems like a good practice in such case.

Comment: I agree it’s a best practice to use a Community Wiki when elevating other contributors’ comments to answers. _Just because a Community Wiki doesn’t contribute to your reputation, however, **doesn’t mean it’s not plagiarism**_. (That’s also why you can’t plagiarize content in Tag Wikis.) Indeed, doing so without attribution effectively launders the licensing requirements of the content, as then other people can cite the Community Wiki without crediting the original author (be that another Stack Overflow contributor from e.g., a comment or answer, or content excerpted from yet another location).

Answer (score 6):

[In a comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user?cb=1#comment169914_288849) you said: *"I'll try to answer more but I'm avoiding downvotes at all costs".* Although I understand that attitude, I urge you to be more daring! If you think the question is worth answering, and that your answer is good, please submit it as an answer, not a comment.

As paxdiablo said, comments are second-class citizens. Although they may be up-voted, comments aren't really a part of the main voting process that affects proper answers. They are ephemeral, like Post-It notes. Also, as  Peter Duniho mentioned, it's annoying to open an allegedly unanswered question only to find an answer buried in the comments.

If you're not prepared to take the risk that your answer might get down-voted, then you don't really have grounds to object if someone else *does* take that risk and turns your comment into an actual answer. As George Stocker mentions, it's nice if people reference your comment when they do that, but they're under no obligation to do so. (FWIW, I sometimes convert comments to answers, but when I do, I always credit the original author).

I should confess that I sometimes put answers in comments. Mostly, they're very simple answers that give a hint or two to the OP of a question which I expect to get closed - I often try to give *some* assistance when I vote to close questions. But sometimes I'll sketch an outline of an answer in a comment in the hope that someone else will take that comment and turn it into a fully-fledged answer. Sure, I miss out on a few points of rep, but I feel that providing a good outline in a comment can encourage the newer SO members to write good answers. And if I don't like the answer they make from my comment I try to help them fix it by writing further comments. :) Sure, this can be more time-consuming than simply writing the answer myself, but I find it rewarding to help others develop their answering skills.

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. It tends to another question I had in mind I was meaning to ask on SO meta (what's the abbreviation for it BTW? SOM? MSO?) that is to say I sometimes see hi-rep users who answer questions in the comment. Despite that is nice to new SO users who are left with good clues to make an proper answer, doesn't this tend to take away the original meaning of SO (which is to avoid answering question in a comment)?

Comment: @D4V1D: Just because someone has hi-rep doesn't mean that everything they do on SO is perfect. :) FWIW, some very knowledgeable hi-rep users got their rep years ago when SO policy was a little different and then they drifted away, but they've recently become active again, so they do stuff that they probably shouldn't... And some people get rep by providing so-so answers to _lots_ of questions - what they lack in quality they make up for in sheer quantity.

Comment: @D4V1D: (cont) But apart from that, it's a common practice of some hi-rep users to provide a quick answer in a comment for a question that they expect to be closed as a duplicate: the comment is provided as a kind of stop-gap answer while they're searching for a good dupe target. Perhaps they ought to delete such comments once the question's closed, but I guess it's not a high priority issue.

Comment: I've had "a hint or two" lead to the OP replying "thx that was the problem" ... and in the case of a 1-rep as-of-today user I mostly don't even bother to flesh out a rather trivial issue.