# What is SO standpoint on comments by A turned into answers by B?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, plagiarism

A question received a comment (which was actually a complete answer) by `UserA`, the OP thanked him and asked him for the comment to be turned into an answer, which he would accept.

This was done by `UserB` (thanking `userA` for his comment).

What should happen now:

- outrage at the plagiarizm?
- it's a jungle and the fittest survives?
- anything else?

The answer is correct, but [we should](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down) ...

> Use your downvotes whenever you encounter an egregiously sloppy,
>   no-effort-expended post, or an answer that is clearly and perhaps
>   dangerously incorrect.

... which is not the case here.

Comment: [This is the official, network-wide, policy](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins). The point is to get quality answers. The answer isn't _"egregiously sloppy"_ or _"dangerously incorrect"_; and the user who commented didn't make it into answer.

Comment: @Ben: (irony aside: this should be an answer IMHO). Very good link, thanks. I failed to mention that I am interested in cases where the time between the comment and the answer is short. But the link you mention makes a clear point.

Comment: It has been stated that it's all up to `UserA` to provide an answer instead of commenting. If `UserB` decide to provide an answer based on `UserA`'s comment, [*it's `UserB`'s gain and `UserA`'s loss*](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user/#comment169982_288847).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with turning comments into answers.

> [This is the official, network-wide, policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/117251/what-should-be-done-with-questions-that-have-been-self-resolved-as-a-comment-ins). The point is to get quality answers. The answer isn't *"egregiously sloppy"* or *"dangerously incorrect"*; and the user who commented didn't make it into answer.
>    - [Ben](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/458741/ben)

This means that SE basically encourages users to use good comments when posting an answer. The entire point of the SE network is based on quality answers.
Users that visit the question a year from now are less likely to look at the comments on a question, than they are to scroll down to the first / highest voted answer.

That said, whenever I (partially) copy a comment into a answer, I make sure it's clear I copied that part of my answer from someone else.

Comment: "...I *make sure it's clear* I copied **that part** of my answer..." Yes, rare is the comment which makes a good answer, quite more often one sees those which are just a seed, or at least a hint. Also, I really mislike answers on off-topic questions, though if they stay comments they at least don't inhibit cleanup.