# Edit to provide credit

Tags: discussion, rejected-edits

According to [this meta post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296763/what-is-so-standpoint-on-comments-by-a-turned-into-answers-by-b), it's fine for a user to turn another user's comment into an answer and one should feel encouraged to provide some credit to the original commenter.  Seeing a similar situation occur in the review queues I made an edit that I thought made the provided credit more clear. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18335492

My initial impression of the answer was that it was responding to another answer and should have been a comment, but when I looked at the question I saw that it was referring to a comment on the question that gave the answer. The user confirms the answer given in the comment in the form of the answer, which should be fine. But the conversational way it's stated was confusing to me. If the original comment with the answer were deleted, future readers might be as perplexed by the phrase "Indeed I also" as I was.

I saw two options: change "Indeed I also" to "I" or morph it to do what it seemed the user was trying to do and give credit to the original commenter but in a more direct manner.

My edit was rejected as superfluous 2 vs 1 and no further updates were made. I'm fairly certain that I'm right that something should be changed here, but perhaps I went about it the wrong way?  Can anyone provide any insights?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The source of the content in that answer is not Martijn Pieters.  The source of that content is the project's documentation (or whatever it is that they checked, which they *should* be specifying in the answer).  That's the canonical source of the information provided.  That someone was inspired to look at that source by another person doesn't require a citation.  If you end up using some information in a paper that you found in a book then you cite the book that you're quoting, not the librarian that told you that the book would have a relevant fact for you.

Comment: Alright great, that makes sense. Am I off-base thinking that the wording `Indeed I also` should simply be change to `I` then? That phrasing just doesn't sit well with me. I was nervous to change the other's intention by removing `Indeed` and `also`, but I feel like it's just a confusing conversational tone added to the answer.

Comment: @JoeyHarwood I wouldn't consider it a useful improvement to the post by itself, but I wouldn't consider it an incorrect change if you included it in a larger edit that actually made meaningful improvements to the post.