# Should I convert somebody else's comment into an answer?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Following the discussion:

[What is SO standpoint on comments by A turned into answers by B?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/296763/what-is-so-standpoint-on-comments-by-a-turned-into-answers-by-b)

consider the situation in which you're "B", and haven't answered yet.

That is, a (reasonable) question has gotten a comment which, essentially, provides an answer; and there are no actual answers posted. You then notice the question, and want to give the same answer as in the comment. Should you...

- write an answer, crediting the comment?
- ask the commenter to make their comment into an answer?
- not do anything?
- do something else?

Comment: The example is from Meta Stack Overflow. Is that the scope here or does it also extend to Stack Overflow (main)?

Comment: @PeterMortensen: My link is not to an example.

Comment: I've done this or rather I've posted an Answer and used a comment in it. I always quote, link to and credit it. Usually people comment because they don't want to write an Answer, so I rarely ask them to do it. If the entire content of the Answer is the comment, then I'd probably pick a community wiki. But I find it irritating that it shows up on my Answer list, since it's technically not even mine.

Comment: @Scratte: In the case motivating me, the commenter did write an answer after I solicited them. What's the basis for your assumption that such commenters usually don't want to write an answer? Has there been some statistical study of this?

Comment: I'm not aware of any study. It's probably just my bias showing its face :( I've seen comments asking others to write Answers that weren't fruitful, but of course I never see the deleted comments after such were fruitful. And me, myself. I very rarely write an Answer if I wrote a comment.

Comment: @Scratte: I sometimes write a comment when I'm not sure it qualifies as an answer, or if I think the question may be a dupe, or if I don't have the time to answer immediately.

Comment: simply add the comentors name to the answer, give the comment more meat and send it

Comment: I see it like this - it's like monopoly. You can decide to not buy a property, at which point it goes up for auction and other players can reap the benefit. Deciding not to write an answer but instead comment is pretty much the same situation, you willingly pass along the opportunity to write it to someone else. And "someone else" should not only feel entitled but proud to write that answer. If that involves copying content from a comment... that is up to the author. It shouldn't ever be necessary, IMO.