# Why was my (accepted) answer deleted?

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers, specific-answer

I recently saw that my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30916139/pmd-warns-use-equals-to-compare-object-references-when-comparing-enums) was deleted:

[image: Deleted answer]

However, I cannot really understand what I did wrong to justify the deletion, how I should edit my post to make it better or how I could prevent something like that in the future. So please share your thoughts with me.

I read the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers), but from my point of view

- It is not a comment
- It is not a question
- It is no "thanks" or "me too" response
- It is not a duplicate of any other answer

Now one can discuss whether it is only a partial and/or link-only answer, but I'd argue that I answered the OP's question ("is the check correct?") and that there is little I could have added more.

Maybe I could have included the points from the second answer, but I didn't want to simply copy it and by the fact that PMD accepted the mentioned behavior as a bug, it should be clear that the code is fine as it is.

There is also a comment underneath the question referring to one of the bugs, but a) my answer was posted before and b) IIRC I originally posted the link as a comment as well and then the OP asked me to write an answer he could accept (but don't nail me down on that). Even if not, [this meta answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288849/4616087) (although maybe not 100% identical) leads me to the conclusion that this would be perfectly fine anyway.

Speaking of the OP, my answer was accepted and still has a score of +3, so it seems it had been helpful for several people, including the OP itself. And isn't that one of the major ideas behind Stack Overflow?

Thank you in advance!

(Update: From another question here on meta I think the reason for deletion might have been that the first version of my answer indeed lacked proper content. But I'd still like to leave this question open for additional input.)

Comment: Yeah, I'm not seeing much wrong with this answer from a moderation standpoint - but that's my personal opinion.  There may be more to this than we know.

Comment: Some people got a lot of time to waste here.... Marvin, don't even try to change minds of people that work with another culture. You are doing good to yourself and anyone who wants it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

As you admit - your first revision did indeed "lack proper content" (although the subsequent revisions put sufficient "meat on the bone" as it were) and it was flagged. I can't speak for George but it's most likely this was an unfortunate "mis-click" when handling the large flag queue mods tackle each day.

I've undeleted your answer - thanks for bringing it to our attention, and apologies for the mishap.

Comment: I feel like this answer should be accepted, then deleted, then undeleted, for the sake of symmetry.

Comment: Well, that was quick! Sounds plausible enough, so I think I'll settle for that explanation. Thanks for undeleting, no offense taken!

Comment: It causes bad PR each time a moderator makes a "mis-click", due to trying to handle quantity over quality. Such a waste of time that @Marvin had to write this question, Jon Clements had to answer it, and 653 people (to date) had to read it. Just to find out that yet again the reason was that a moderator did not make/take/find the time to do it correctly. I can see no reason looking at the history for George to have deleted it.

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier: On the other hand, we (developers) are so used to stupid bugs that mis-clicks should not faze us :)

Comment: @RichardLeMesurier Mod's are only human and are doing this for free.  I think giving them a little slack is more than called for.  If we see one post on meta about a bad decision/miss click there were probably thousands of flags that the mods handled correctly.

Comment: As far as I'm concerned I don't bear a grudge against anyone. Mistakes happen. In fact (but in no way intended) the "meta effect" has already more than tripled the upvotes, making that answer my most "successful" one so far. I'm almost tempted to thank George for deleting it, but that's an entirely different story and cannot be the goal behind SO (plus the effect seems to be already widely discussed here on meta as well).

Comment: This is SO Streisand!