# should we give answer to a question which already got an answer in comments

Tags: discussion

I am going through Magento unanswered questions and found that there is a [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32522387/404-page-when-i-click-on-custom-configuration-tab-in-magento) with no answer. I know the answer but I found that there is an answer in comments which already solved the problem of a user.

is it good to give answer to such a question?
if I give answer to that question I might have chance of downvote because it is already answer in comments.

what should need to do?

Comment: Don't hesitate to post an answer, even though the question has been resolved via comments. As the placeholder in the comment box says: "*Avoid answering questions in comments*". See also [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user).

Comment: but what about the user who think it just copy my comment and paste that in answer.

Comment: You shouldn't answer question in comments. If you gain reputation by using comments, it's your gain and their loss (see the link in the above comment).

Comment: yeah , you are right. and glad to know that you already faced the issue ;)

Comment: @D4V1D : I think you can also provide the answer of this question.