# What to do when someone just collect a series of comments and make it an answer

Tags: discussion

In many occasions, users help the OP with comments in its question and many times a comment is just the right answer. When this happens to me, I tell the user that his comment help me solve my problem and ask him if he want to make its comment an answer and I will accept it. Like in this question for example:

[Vectorize access to columns in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35914984/vectorize-access-to-columns-in-r)

But what should I do when I am the one that helped the OP and other user just collect what other users and me wrote in the comments, make it an answer and the OP accept it?

Comment: Thanks, I've search before asking the question for “comments” and things on those lines but didn't find what I want to ask. I am going to read that question.

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user

Comment: It is probably more a duplicate of that link you've posted, but the answer is the same, if it concerns you then post the comment as an answer. It is just the way it goes sometimes when you've not entirely got a grip on the problem someone is stating and you just want to suggest an solution before you write it as an answer. The end result is if you helped that person that's the good part, if someone else gets the points for that, then that's just life sometimes.