# Is it alright to submit an answer if an answer has already been given in the comment?

Tags: discussion, answers, comments, etiquette

Often when a fresh question arises, the correct answer is given as a comment. Because it is  given as a comment, it is submitted quickly, however it does contain the essence of the answer. Is it ethically OK to then submit an answer subsequently when such a comment exists? It feels like the commenter deserves to be recognized as the true answerer, not someone who comes in afterwards in the Answer section; and who may have used the comment to form the answer.

(The fact that all responses have been comments and no answers is very meta!)

Comment: Somewhat depends on who you ask. But if you want to really take the high ground, do the following: post an answer, make it a community wiki, and attribute both the commenter (via a link to profile) and their comment (by quoting the original comment as they tend to go poof over time) - you will do a great service to the community! If you can expand on the comment in a meaningful way, skip the community wiki part and just get your well-deserved praise if it is any good

Comment: [This post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288847/what-to-do-when-my-comment-has-been-reposted-as-an-answer-by-another-user) is your question but in reverse, but [the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/288849) is really the same. Go ahead and post your own answer, and mention & link the comment if you feel it would be appropriate. But yes, it's ethically OK– answers belong in _answers_ on main sites, not comments!

Comment: Ethically, I would say it's fine. The original commenter misses out on any upvotes, but by commenting instead of answering they also avoided any potential downvotes. That said, sometimes people answer in the comments because they want to help but they also think the question should be closed, so be careful not to answer questions which should instead be closed as off-topic or duplicates.